# need help to incorporate this 2nd function into my program

Tags: c++

hi so i'm making a program that will ask the user to enter an integer and spit it back out in roman numerals.  i had it working so the roman numeral part would work but i couldn't loop the program.  now i have the program looped but i can't get the roman numeral function to work.  the program executes but it's as if function1 doesn't exist and i dont know how to get the main function to use it.  i have to keep all user interaction in the main function.  i want the cout << roman << endl; line to spit out the integer in roman numerals but it's not working.  this is only my 2nd assignment ever so any help would be appreciated!  thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
string roman;
int integer;
int num;

char answer;

int main()
{
  while (true)
  {
    cout << "Enter Integer " << endl;
    cin >> integer;
    cout << roman << endl;
    cout << "convert another (y/n)? " << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'n' || answer == 'N')
        break;
  }
}

int function1()
{
  if ((integer >= 4000) || (integer <= 0))
  {
    cout << endl << "Invalid Integer" << endl;
  }
  //3286
  else
  {
    if (integer >= 1000)
    {
        num = (integer / 1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            roman += 'M';
        }
        integer %= 1000;
        // care ^^^
    }
    // 286
    if (integer >= 100)
    {
        num = (integer / 100);

        if (num == 9)
        {
            roman += "CM";
        }
        else if (num >= 5)
        {
            roman += 'D';

            for (int i = 0; i < num - 5; i++)
            {
                roman += 'C';
            }
        }
        else if (num == 4)
        {
            roman += "CD";
        }
        else if (num >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                roman += 'C';
            }
        }
        integer %= 100;
    }

    // 86
    if (integer >= 10)
    {
        num = (integer / 10);

        if (num == 9)
        {
            roman += "XC";
        }
        else if (num >= 5)
        {
            roman += 'L';

            for (int i = 0; i < num - 5; i++)
            {
                roman += 'X';
            }
        }
        else if (num == 4)
        {
            roman += "XL";
        }
        else if (num >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                roman += 'X';
            }
        }
        integer %= 10;
        // 6

    }

    if (integer >= 1)
    {
        num = integer;

        if (num == 9)
        {
            roman += "IX";
        }
        else if (num >= 5)
        {
            roman += "V";

            for (int i = 0; i < num - 5; i++)
            {
                roman += 'I';
            }
        }
        else if (num == 4)
        {
            roman += "IV";
        }
        else if (num >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                roman += 'I';
            }
        }
    }


    cout << "--> " << roman << endl;

}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get a clear image of the problem from your question, but you never actually call `function1`.

Comment: When you write code, start with something simple that works, then add complexity a little at a time. When you write `function1` (bad name, btw, I'd suggest something like `Roman`), start with a function that converts any number into "X". *Get that to work before you attempt anything more complex.* That approach will save you a lot of wasted time.

Comment: Perhaps using identifiers with meaningful names will help you and us

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call function1, for example:

```
while (true)
{
    cout << "Enter Integer " << endl;
    cin >> integer;
    function1();
    cout << roman << endl;
    cout << "convert another (y/n)? " << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'n' || answer == 'N')
        break;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you're looking for good ways to improve your program, first I'd treat function1 like an actual function - take an integer parameter and return a string, have a scope for it. Don't bother having a "integer" be a global and don't have "roman" at all - that's what parameter-passing and return values are for. Have num be declared inside the function - noone outside your function needs to know what temporary variables are contained in it. Right now function1 is basically usable once, in one place.